# What is the difference between setObject:forKey setObject:forKeyedSubscript

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Is there any difference between the methods `setObject:forKey` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript`?

I am using an Objective-C `NSMutableArray`. Both seem to function the same way to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` and `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` are used for mutable collection subscripting methods, introduced with the Objective C Literals.

`setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` is used for dictionary-styled mutable collections. You should not use it with array-style collections.

More info [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

"This method is identical to setObject:forKey:".

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why it's there then?

Comment: Or at least provide the documentation.

Comment: It is used to provide literals support. If I write `myDict[@"key"] = @"bob";`, then Objective-C calls the `setObject:forKeyedSubscript` method like this: `[myDict setObject:@"bob" forKeyedSubscript:@"key"];`. Make sense now?

Comment: It claims it is identical, but `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` allows `nil` values (which removes the key and value from the dictionary), whereas `setObject:forKey:` will raise an `NSInvalidArgumentException` if you pass it a `nil` value!